# Windows 8 Default User doesn't have all of the Admin permissions

Tags: windows-8, permissions

So I recently bought Windows 8 and I am still in the process of getting everything setup and properly working.

My current issue is that the default account, the one made during the setup, doesn't have all of the administration permissions that I think it should have. For example, I can only create a folder in program files, and even then I need to authorize it.

> Here are screenshots of my situation and permissions: [Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QveBX.jpg)

I would like for my account to be able to do *everything* without having to authorize it before hand...

*I can't most Screen shots or more links due to my lack of 'reputation'.*

Comment: Program Files is a protected directory by design.  It's also not possible to fully disable UAC on Windows 8.0 or Windows 8.1

Comment: did you have this in windows 7? maybe there's a way to log in as administrator there may have been in win7 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loU9qJd28hM  what did you do in win7? or are you coming straight from XP?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the permissions for Program Files? Sometimes you can't set full control inheritable from root level, so go to the problem directory and make sure full control is set there -  - and make sure the permissions are inherited.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  Windows also does not have "root"

Comment: @Ramhound it is quite common for people to describe it as the "root of the filesystem" (similar to the root of a tree) when they are talking about filesystems in general especially where multiple drives are involved and you mean "the root folder of any drive". In that context the answer is fine.